# Conversion of PLSQL to TSQL

Tags: t-sql, plsql

I am Oracle guy with no experience in SQL Server and have been hired to make ERDs/DDLs for a job in SQL Server. I've finished the ERD and have presented DDL statements, but am now additionally being requested to do application logic as well. I enjoy doing application logic in PL/SQL and figure it won't be so hard for me to translate the logic into TSQL procs without much studying. Is this an accurate belief?

I know absolutely no TSQL.

Comment: how much Tsql do you know? its depend on it.

Comment: @Hiten004 Absolutely none. codingbiz Would it be accurate to state that they only vary by syntax, or are there other differences?

Comment: Most times it is syntax. But there are some features in PL/SQL missing in TSQL and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSQL is not difficult to learn. You should be up to speed in a day if you are serious about it. Just learn the basics and then the differences. Pick up some tutorials on the internet and do some practices.

You can pay attention to these and more

- Conditional statement - IF, Loops
- Cursors
- Variable declaration
- Assignment statement
- Stored Procedures
- Functions
- and more

Like you could do a comprehensive search - TSQL vs PL/SQL, or Differences between PL/SQL and TSQL